# Are the following boolean expressions correct according to De Morgan's laws?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

Are the below boolean expressions correct according to De Morgan's laws?

I am trying to realise a three input NOR gate using a four input NOR gate, but I suspect I did a wrong transform.

1. \$\:\:\:y=\overline{a+b+c+d}=\overline{a+b+c}\:*\:\:\bar{d}=\:\:...\$
2. \$\:\:\:y=\overline{a}\:*\:\:\bar{b}=\overline{a}\:*\:\:\overline{b+b}=\overline{a+(b+b)}=\overline{a+b+b}=\:\:...\$

Comment: If you suspect you did something wrong in your steps, then please show us your approach. It's impossible to spot your mental errors if you haven't disclosed your mental steps. You just leave us guessing, then. Would you please show us those transforms you did?

Comment: I just mean if I can (for inputs: a, b, c, d) make following equation: y=!(a+b+c+d)=!(a+b+c)*!d

Comment: Set \$e=a+b+c\$. Then \$y=\overline{e+d}=\overline{e\vphantom{d}}\cdot\overline{d}=\overline{a+b+c\vphantom{d}}\cdot\overline{d}\$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. is correct as written.  "If you break/unbreak the over-bar, you change the sign".  If you mentally assign a variable (call it *u*) for "a+b+c", then you are equating ~(u+d) with (~u)&(~d) which is correct and is clearly breaking-the-overbar-while-changing-the-sign.  So 1) is good.
2. is also correct, although you took a strange detour.  For any *x* you can replace it with (*x* + *x*) and similarly with (*x* & *x*).  So, ~a * ~b becomes immediately ~(a+b) which is of course ~(a+b+b) and similarly ~(a+a+a+a+a+b+b+(aa)+(bb)+(bb)+(aa)) and so on.